# SQL Error / SORT BY breaks PHP

Tags: php, sql

My 1st statement works great, but I want to order the statement and get back the results by highest percentage 1st [meta_value]

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "win_percentage"
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_id] => 417
            [post_id] => 59
            [meta_key] => win_percentage
            [meta_value] => 9.3023255814
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [meta_id] => 419
            [post_id] => 62
            [meta_key] => win_percentage
            [meta_value] => 6.66666666667
        )

)

SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "win_percentage" ORDER BY = meta_value ASC
```

FAILED

Comment: WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= "meta_value" ASC' at line 1]
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "win_percentage" ORDER BY = "meta_value" ASC

Answer (score 1):

Remove `=` after ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "win_percentage" ORDER BY meta_value ASC
```

Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY {COLUMN_NAME}` not use `=` with order by.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = "win_percentage" ORDER BY meta_value ASC
```